# Moto G2 is not starting

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g2

I have MOTO g2. Yesterday night, I was uninstalling some apps to free up the memory and by mistake I disabled few google apps and force stopped google play. Then, the menu was not started and hence I switched off mobile.

After switching on, my mobile was displaying optimizing app x of x and after all apps were optimized, it again restarted and again this optimizing app came up. This is like a loop. I can't make it stop. I went into recovery mode and cleared cache, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone rooted / bootloader unlocked? If it is, then you can do an adb pull of your entire internal storage so that you may still be able to retrieve all your data intact.

A sure shot way of fixing this would be to factory reset your phone via the stock recovery, but at the moment, that might be a rather extreme step.

The steps have been listed in [moto's official help page](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/99825/p/30,6720,9151)

```
External Reset (Lollipop)

1. With the phone powered off, press and hold the Volume Down button and the Power button at the same time until the device turns on. You will see the word "Start" with an arrow around it.

2. Press the Volume Down button twice to highlight "Recovery mode"

3. Press the Volume Up button to restart into Recovery mode. You'll see an image of an Android robot with a red exclamation mark and the words "No command."

4. While holding down the Power button, press the Volume Up button.

5. Use the volume buttons to scroll to "wipe data/factory reset" and press the Power button to select it.

6. Scroll down to "Yes - erase all user data" and press the Power button to select it.
```

Comment: It's not rooted. But I don't know whether bootloader is unlocked. How do I know whether bootloader is unlocked ? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: If you've not unlocked it, then it's locked. Either way, the option of retrieving it  via adb sounds far fetched since you will need to first enable the option in developer settings - this you will not be able to since you're in a bootloop.